# Jersey Client - send gzip file got error: The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream

Tags: jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have to call a webservice and it requires to set header("x-ms-blob-type","blockblob") and put a file in gzip. I am trying to use the FormDataMultiple to set the file and send it as an Entity. This is what I did.

The server responded the they got the file but when they tried to process the file it gave me back with this error:

"Error parsing file: The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.”

```
final FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", new File("/Users/Downloads/bulk.gz"),MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);

FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();

final FormDataMultiPart multipart = (FormDataMultiPart) formDataMultiPart.bodyPart(filePart);

final Response response = target.request()
                          .header("Content-Type", "application/x-gzip")
                          .header("x-ms-blob-type","blockblob")
                          .put(Entity.entity(multipart,multipart.getMediaType()));
```

What should I do? I think it would be better if I can pass a gzip input stream to the request instead of using the Multiple Part Form.

Best Regards,
Robert

Comment: Are you sure they *want* a `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: I am not so sure. So, I tried to use the multipart/form-data. But, it seems not to be the case. I just tried again and use PUT with OutputStream and it worked. Thank you for your response,  Hobbs.